# SPY GAME: Write a function that takes in a list of integers and returns True if it contains 007 in order

Tags: python, while-loop

I have written a code for the above problem but I have a doubt since this code returns 1 more 0 value for list containing [0,0,7,0,0], I can make the len to <=2 but I can't understand why it doesn't stop as soon as it hits 3 numbers in the list

```
nums = []
def spy_game(nums):
    mynewlist = []
    
    for i in nums:
        while len(mynewlist)<=3:
            if i ==0:
                mynewlist.append(i)
                break
                
            elif  i==7:
                mynewlist.append(i)
                break   
            
            break
      
    return mynewlist == [0,0,7]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We do not "find the bug" for people here. Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and carefully study what happens step by step when the code runs; and then if you still cannot understand the result, ask a *specific* question about where the code does a specific thing that is different from what you expect (explain exactly what you think should have happened instead at that point, and why).

Comment: This is not a solution for your problem but an alternative implementation because your code is far too complicated. One line of code in the function is enough: `return True if any(nums[i:i + 3] == [0, 0, 7] for i in range(len(nums)-2)) else False`.

Answer (score 0):

You have put a `while` loop inside the `for` loop, that means

- **for each** value of the initial list

  - add it to mynewlist 3 times

That isn't what you need, just add the zeros and seven. But also the 007 pattern may not be at the beginning

With this `[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,7]` if you stop at 3 values you'll have `[0,0,0]`

---

I'd suggest you add every zero and seven to a list, keep only the last 3 of them, and if it is the 007 pattern then you're good, but if at the end of the loop you haven't find it, you return false

```
def spy_game(nums):
    mynewlist = []
    for value in nums:
        if value in (0, 7):
            mynewlist.append(value)
        # keep only last 3
        mynewlist = mynewlist[-3:]
        if mynewlist == [0, 0, 7]:
            return True
    return False
```

That is just an efficient way of filtering to every 0 and 7, and then looking for the 007 pattern

Answer (score 0):

Use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=deque#collections.deque) and keep the length of queue at 3:

```py
def spy_game(nums):
    import collections
    mynewqueue = collections.deque()
    target = collections.deque([0,0,7])
    
    for i in nums:
        mynewqueue.append(i)
        if len(mynewqueue) > 3:
            _ = mynewqueue.popleft()
        if mynewqueue == target:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for the pattern 007 appearing consecutively somewhere in the list, why not iterate over a range of length-3 splices like this?

```
def spy_game(nums):
    for i in range(len(nums)-2):
        if nums[i:i+3] == [0,0,7]:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: The reason it doesn't stop as soon as it hits 3 numbers is that you are checking the length condition before appending the list, so when the length is 3 the while condition is true and the loop runs one more iteration appending 0 to your list if 0 comes after 7

Answer (score 0):

Your `while len(mynewlist)<=3:` never iterates more than once so it could be a simple if statement.  Once mynewlist has 4 items in it, there is no logic to reset or shift it to take into account subsequent items of `nums`.  There are 4 items in mynewlist at the end because you are going into your while statement when the list already has 3 items (because of `<= 3`).

Assuming you're looking for 0,0,7 in consecutive items, you could use zip to form tuples of 3 consecutive items and check if (0,0,7) is in there:

```
def spy_game(nums):
    return (0,0,7) in zip(nums,nums[1:],nums[2:])
```

If your functions needs to allow intermediate values betwen the zeros or between the second zero and the seven (e.g. [0,3,0,1,2,7]), you can filter out the other numbers before applying the same logic:

```
def spy_game(nums):
    nums07 = [ n for n in nums if n in (0,7) ]
    return (0,0,7) in zip(nums07, nums07[1:], nums07[2:])
```